# The Session graph is empty. Add operations to the graph before calling run(). [tf2]

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

It was a work about training a neural network with keras in Google Colab.  After running these cells,

```
def flow_from_dataframe(idg, 
                    in_df, 
                    path_col,
                    y_col, 
                    shuffle = True, 
                    color_mode = 'rgb'):
files_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((in_df[path_col].values, 
                                               np.stack(in_df[y_col].values,0)))
in_len = in_df[path_col].values.shape[0]
while True:
    if shuffle:
        files_ds = files_ds.shuffle(in_len) # shuffle the whole dataset
    
    next_batch = idg(files_ds).repeat().make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
    for i in range(max(in_len//32,1)):
        # NOTE: if we loop here it is 'thread-safe-ish' if we loop on the outside it is completely unsafe
        yield K.get_session().run(next_batch)


batch_size = 48
core_idg = tf_augmentor(out_size = IMG_SIZE, 
                        color_mode = 'rgb', 
                        vertical_flip = True,
                        crop_probability=0.0, # crop doesn't work yet
                        batch_size = batch_size) 
valid_idg = tf_augmentor(out_size = IMG_SIZE, color_mode = 'rgb', 
                         crop_probability=0.0, 
                         horizontal_flip = False, 
                         vertical_flip = False, 
                         random_brightness = False,
                         random_contrast = False,
                         random_saturation = False,
                         random_hue = False,
                         rotation_range = 0,
                        batch_size = batch_size)

train_gen = flow_from_dataframe(core_idg, train_df, path_col = 'path', y_col = 'level_cat')

valid_gen = flow_from_dataframe(valid_idg, valid_df, path_col = 'path', y_col = 'level_cat') 
# we can use much larger batches for evaluation

t_x, t_y = next(valid_gen)
fig, m_axs = plt.subplots(2, 4, figsize = (16, 8))
for (c_x, c_y, c_ax) in zip(t_x, t_y, m_axs.flatten()):
    c_ax.imshow(np.clip(c_x*127+127, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8))
    c_ax.set_title('Severity {}'.format(np.argmax(c_y, -1)))
    c_ax.axis('off')
```

I get this error:

```
'RepeatDataset' object has no attribute 'make_one_shot_iterator'
```

After applying fix from this [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/29252)

```
def flow_from_dataframe(idg, 
                        in_df, 
                        path_col,
                        y_col, 
                        shuffle = True, 
                        color_mode = 'rgb'):
    files_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((in_df[path_col].values, 
                                                   np.stack(in_df[y_col].values,0)))
    in_len = in_df[path_col].values.shape[0]
    while True:
        if shuffle:
            files_ds = files_ds.shuffle(in_len) # shuffle the whole dataset
       

            for next_batch in files_ds:
                tf.print(next_batch)
            for i in range(max(in_len//32,1)):
                # NOTE: if we loop here it is 'thread-safe-ish' if we loop on the outside it is completely unsafe
                yield K.get_session().run(next_batch)
                
batch_size = 48
core_idg = tf_augmentor(out_size = IMG_SIZE, 
                        color_mode = 'rgb', 
                        vertical_flip = True,
                        crop_probability=0.0, # crop doesn't work yet
                        batch_size = batch_size) 
valid_idg = tf_augmentor(out_size = IMG_SIZE, color_mode = 'rgb', 
                         crop_probability=0.0, 
                         horizontal_flip = False, 
                         vertical_flip = False, 
                         random_brightness = False,
                         random_contrast = False,
                         random_saturation = False,
                         random_hue = False,
                         rotation_range = 0,
                        batch_size = batch_size)

train_gen = flow_from_dataframe(core_idg, train_df, path_col = 'path', y_col = 'level_cat')

valid_gen = flow_from_dataframe(valid_idg, valid_df, path_col = 'path', y_col = 'level_cat') 
# we can use much larger batches for evaluation

t_x, t_y = next(valid_gen)
fig, m_axs = plt.subplots(2, 4, figsize = (16, 8))
for (c_x, c_y, c_ax) in zip(t_x, t_y, m_axs.flatten()):
    c_ax.imshow(np.clip(c_x*127+127, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8))
    c_ax.set_title('Severity {}'.format(np.argmax(c_y, -1)))
    c_ax.axis('off')
```

I encounter this,

```
The Session graph is empty.  Add operations to the graph before calling run().
```

After researching the error I changed some parts of the code following this [link](https://github.com/OlafenwaMoses/ImageAI/issues/400)

```
def flow_from_dataframe(idg, 
                        in_df, 
                        path_col,
                        y_col, 
                        shuffle = True, 
                        color_mode = 'rgb'):
    files_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((in_df[path_col].values, 
                                                   np.stack(in_df[y_col].values,0)))
    in_len = in_df[path_col].values.shape[0]
    while True:
        if shuffle:
            files_ds = files_ds.shuffle(in_len) # shuffle the whole dataset
        #def generator(dataset_iterator, default_graph):
          #with tf.Session(graph=default_graph) as sess:
            #next_batch = idg(files_ds).repeat().make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
            for next_batch in files_ds:
                tf.print(next_batch)
            for i in range(max(in_len//32,1)):
                # NOTE: if we loop here it is 'thread-safe-ish' if we loop on the outside it is completely unsafe
                
                print(sess.run(next_batch))

batch_size = 48
core_idg = tf_augmentor(out_size = IMG_SIZE, 
                        color_mode = 'rgb', 
                        vertical_flip = True,
                        crop_probability=0.0, # crop doesn't work yet
                        batch_size = batch_size) 
valid_idg = tf_augmentor(out_size = IMG_SIZE, color_mode = 'rgb', 
                         crop_probability=0.0, 
                         horizontal_flip = False, 
                         vertical_flip = False, 
                         random_brightness = False,
                         random_contrast = False,
                         random_saturation = False,
                         random_hue = False,
                         rotation_range = 0,
                        batch_size = batch_size)

train_gen = flow_from_dataframe(core_idg, train_df, path_col = 'path', y_col = 'level_cat')

valid_gen = flow_from_dataframe(valid_idg, valid_df, path_col = 'path', y_col = 'level_cat') 
# we can use much larger batches for evaluation
```

but this time encountered the same error  but this time it was before the validation cell.

What am I supposed to do?

P.S: I'm new in this subject and English is not my first language. Sorry for the mess.